# Ada 83 Address to Array Conversion

Tags: arrays, ada

In the code I inherited, a buffer is passed to a procedure using its start address and length as parameters. This procedure code uses inline assembly language to process the buffer contents.

In a new procedure that uses the same parameters, I want to refer to the buffer as an array but I want to use the same parameters and their types that the existing procedure uses. This is so I don't have to make intrusive modifications to the original code except to use the same calling signature, which is like this:

```
procedure Push_Buffer(
    Source_Address : Address;
    Count          : Natural);
```

In this case, the buffer is just an array of machine words. I want to refer to it as an array of machine words, and already have types (Word and Buffer_Type) that are used elsewhere without a problem. (The objects of unconstrained type Buffer_Type have their constraints defined where they are used.)

I would like to refer to the buffer that's being passed by address as an array within my procedure. How would I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this (which works with `-gnat83`, but might not work with a real Ada83 compiler; I don’t have one to check with):

```
with Text_IO; use Text_IO;
with System;
procedure Push is
   type Integers is array (Positive range <>) of Integer;

   procedure Push_Buffer (Source_Address : System.Address;
                          Count : Natural) is
      Source : Integers (1 .. Count);
      for Source use at Source_Address;
   begin
      for J in Source'Range loop
         Put_Line (Integer'Image (J) & " => " & Integer'Image (Source (J)));
      end loop;
   end Push_Buffer;

begin
   declare
      Data : Integers (1 .. 3) := (4, 5, 6);
   begin
      Push_Buffer (Data'Address, Data'Length);
   end;
end Push;
```

As a side note, probably not relevant to your situation: if there was any question of default initialization of the object whose address you’ve specified (for example, if it’s a structure containing access variables, which are default-initialized to `null`) you would need to suppress the initialization by writing the declaration as

```
  Source : Integers (1 .. Count);
  pragma Import (Ada, Source);
  for Source use at Source_Address;
```

(or something compiler-dependent like that; GNAT says `warning: (Ada 83) pragma "Import" is non-standard`). See the [GNAT Reference Manual 8.15, Address Clauses](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gnat_rm/Address-Clauses.html), about half-way down.

Comment: This is working for me in GNAT. I'm eventually targeting a different architecture, and will use a different compiler. I'm new at Ada, so I'm not sure which part you think may not work in another compiler. I need to understand the *for/use* statement before the *begin*. (I am a bit familiar with *for/use at*.) I would have thought that was evaluated during compile and link rather than during run time, but my own docs say it "need not be static". The object whose address I am referencing contains only data, and not access variables.

Comment: `for Source'Address use Source_Address` is Ada 95 syntax; the equivalent Ada 83 syntax is `for Source use at Source_Address`.

Comment: @Jim I posted my comment before I read all of yours.  The two syntaxes (`for Source'address use` and `for Source use at`) are equivalent.  The former was introduced in Ada 95 because the syntax was going to be used for many new attributes, and they wanted to make things consistent.

Comment: By the way, make sure you test this on every compiler you implement it on.  Since `Source` is a subtype of an unconstrained array, and compilers have to do some special things when dealing with unconstrained arrays (bounds have to be stored somewhere), there's a chance that `Source_Address` will apply to some other data than the first element of the array.  I think the standard makes the exact meaning of this clause implementation-dependent, although I'm not sure.

Comment: @ajb I did see that with an erroneous count value  the code happily behaved just like C pointers would and crossed into other data (easily recognized from a record that contained the Source array). I assume that the burden is on my code to watch for array boundaries, but that's okay if the code is compliant with the standard.

Comment: @ajb, I originally used the aspect form until I re-read the question title.

Answer (score 0):

I would use an unconstrained array as the parameter, rather than a System.Address. This ensures that the compiler does not pass the bound information (aka "fat pointers" in gcc and gnat), and should be compatible with a pragma import.

```
type Unconstrained_Integer_Array is array (Positive) of Integer;
procedure Push_Buffer (Buffer : Unconstrained_Integer_Array;
                       Length : Natural)
is
begin
    for A in 1 .. Length loop
          ...
    end loop;
end Push_Buffer;
```

We use similar tricks when interfacing with C in the GtkAda bindings

Comment: "Should be compatible with a pragma import"--this is HIGHLY compiler-dependent.  Do not count on this.  Test it on any compiler you plan to use.  Please note that the OP stated in comments that he plans to use non-GNAT compilers.

Comment: And he also says "I want to use the same parameters and their types that the existing procedure uses. This is so I don't have to make intrusive modifications to the original code except to use the same calling signature"